# Phasing problem using "samtools phase"

Tags: sam, fasta, samtools, phase

so I'm having a problem using [samtools phase](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-phase.html). I'm trying to phase my .bam archives that where generated by aligning my samples with my reference genome. Following the documentation I tried the command:

`samtools phase -A  my_referenceGenome.fasta   my_sample_toBePhased.bam`

The -A flag stands for dropping reads with ambiguous phase. The **error** I get is: `[W::sam_read1] Parse error at line 1`. I generated .bam files with and without the SAM header but the error persists.

I feel like I am missing something basic but that isn't clearly stated anywere. Does the `my_referenceGenome.fasta` archive needs to be previously phased? If so, how can I do it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I see in my samtools phase (v1.10)

```
Usage:   samtools phase [options] <in.bam>
```

samtools phase only takes a bam file as an input. But you are specifying a .fasta file as an input. If you want to specify the reference genome, you should be using the argument "--reference" as described here

```
      --reference FILE
           Reference sequence FASTA FILE [null]
```

Comment: Oh, you're right! I also tried that but it didn't work. I managed to make it work and I'll add an answer shortly. But before that I want to ask a little question:  in my pipeline I also remove pcr duplicates with the fixmate/markdup steps. Is it better to phase the reads before or after removing the duplicates?

Comment: I would recommend removing duplicates first.